# Pointer to pointers in C++ without the new keyword

Tags: c++, pointers

What is the different between the following two lines of code in C++?

**Line1:**

```
MyClass ** objects = new MyClass * [Number];
```

**Line2**

```
MyClass *  objects [Number];
```

Comment: you sure this is c++?

Comment: @BufBills Why wouldn't it be?

Comment: This is a general-reference question. Consult [your favorite book on the C++ language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to see what the `new` operator does, how objects are allocated with automatic storage duration, and how pointers work.

Comment: Same as the difference between `int foo[10];` and `int *foo = new int[10];`.

Comment: The first creates a *dynamic* array of pointers from the *free store* (heap), the second  creates an array of pointers as a local *automatic* variable (on the stack) that will be deleted automatically when it goes out of scope.

Comment: So *(objects+2) for Line 1 is equivalent to objects[2] for Line 2?

Comment: `*(objects+2)` is equivalent to `objects[2]` for *both* of them. The access syntax is the same for both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line1 defines a pointer to pointer to object and it contains initializer.
The second line (line2) defines an array of pointers to objects. This array is not initialized in any way.

Comment: By initializing you mean giving some initial values to the objects?

Comment: No, not to the MyClass objects. In Line1 your variable `objects` after initialization starts to point to a number of pointers (array of pointres). And elements of this array are not initialized.